# Spring Roo 1.23 and TIMESTAMP field

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, spring-roo

I'm using spring, hibernate and dbms oracle.

I have next problem with using spring roo v1.23:

When i'm making **database reverse engineer** db managed aspects with **timestamp**, fields are generating with **Calendar** type. After this i need to configure my beans on **Date** type manually.
Version 1.22 of roo generates **Date** type as i need.

Is it possible to make spring roo 1.23 working for the timestamp fields as 1.22 ?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly add a **Date** field in your entity class?
According to Spring Doc, if there is existing field in the entity, spring will ignore this field and not create this field in .aj file.

Comment: I know that. The problem is that i have big database and i must make it manually for all tables with timestamp fields. I'm wasting my time. :-)

Comment: @Damask I am having the same problem, did you solve the issue?

Comment: No, we just changed back fields type in DB to Date. It wasn't principal.